How may earned runs in this situation?
B1-Single
B2-FC safe at 1st B1 out at second
B3-Walk
B4-Walk
B5-E5 Safe at third B2, B3, B4 score
B6-E2 safe at first B5 scores
B7-BB
B8-BB
B9-FC 2 out
B10-FC 3 out

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You need to replay the inning as if the fielders were able to play the balls without errors and see how you think it would have turned out.   Just the fact that there was an error may not be sufficient.   The type of error also matters.
For instance in the B5 play, was this a strong drive deep to the outfield with a relay trying to stop the batter from turning it into a triple, but the third baseman missed the catch?   If so, you assume the preceding runners would have scored without the error and all three runs would be earned...
Or was it instead a ball near third that should have been caught preventing any runners from advancing, but instead everyone tears around the bases while the ball dribbled down the third base line?  In that case (depending on how you rule later plays), it could be that all the runs are unearned.
From the information shown, I'm guessing you could have between 0 and 3 earned.   I'm not really thinking up any normal scenarios where you could get those errors and more than 3 runs earned.
